# sumar valores a un diccionario en compresión de diccionario

Tags: python

Me encontraba dando respuesta a un pregunta, durante mi proceso de pruebas para dar con la solución mi idea fue hacer una compresión de diccionario, el problema consistía en recorrer una lista con diccionarios e ir sumando los valores.

**Lista**

```py
clientes = [
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 30000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 22000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 28000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 23000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 18000
    }
]
```

El resultado debía ser un diccionario con la suma del total a pagar en cada caso, algo así (ignorar la clave `total`):

```
{
  'total': 191000, 
  'amazon_prime': 103000, 
  'netflix': 88000
}
```

Bien, para esto una de mis soluciones fue la siguiente:

```py
{clientes[i]["abonado"]:clientes[i]["valor_a_pagar"] for i in range(len(clientes)) }
```

Sin embargo esto me devuelve solo el ultimo valor.

```
{
  'amazon_prime': 23000, 
  'netflix': 18000
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo ir sumando los valores a mi diccionario utilizando una compresión de diccionario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes, y no debieras. Por definición, una [comprensión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) es:

> a syntactic construct available in some programming languages for creating a list **based on existing lists**.

El énfasis es mio. Mi traducción:

> Una construcción sintáctica disponible en algunos lenguajes de programación para crear una lista **basada en otras listas**.

Y lo que tu quieres es crear, en este caso, un diccionario, basado en otro diccionario **y el estado actual del nuevo diccionario**.

Esto, conceptualmente, ya no es una comprensión, es otra cosa.

En cambio, hay otra construcción que puedes utilizar: **fold** (en inglés)

Para hacer **fold** en python, puedes valerte de la función `reduce` de `functools`. Por ejemplo, puedes encontrar el resultado exacto que buscas, en un formato similar al que propones, con la expresión:

```
import functools

resumen = functools.reduce(lambda resumen, i: {**resumen, clientes[i]["abonado"]:resumen.get(clientes[i]["abonado"], 0) + clientes[i]["valor_a_pagar"]}, range(len(clientes)), {})

print(resumen)
```

Con tus datos, produce la siguiente salida:

```
{'amazon_prime': 103000, 'netflix': 88000}
```

Ya que el diccionario original es iterable, puedes simplificar la expresión a:

```
resumen = functools.reduce(lambda resumen, cliente: {**resumen, cliente["abonado"]:resumen.get(cliente["abonado"], 0) + cliente["valor_a_pagar"]}, clientes, {})
```

Que produce el mismo resultado.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, fue muy simplificada

Answer (score 3):

El propósito de la comprensión de listas es crear una nueva lista, no el fungir como una función reductora. Antes de la existencia de la comprensión de lista, se utilizaba funciones de orden superior tales como map, reduce, filter, etc. Actualmente la comprensión de lista logra abarcar gran parte de los casos de uso de map y/o filter, sin embargo reduce sigue siendo ideal para aquellos casos donde se requiere reducir una lista de objetos a un objeto, en este caso un objeto con el acumulado de los importes por plataforma (netflix, amazon..).

El programa completo sería algo así...

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from functools import reduce


clientes = [
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 30000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 22000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 28000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 23000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 18000
    }
]


@dataclass
class Registro:
    amazon_prime: float = 0.0
    netflix: float = 0.0


def registrar(registro, cliente):
    destino = cliente['abonado'] # Netflix / Amazon prime
    setattr(registro, destino, getattr(registro, destino) + cliente['valor_a_pagar']) # Sumar lo acumulado mas el nuevo importe
    return registro

registro = reduce(registrar, clientes, Registro())
print(asdict(registro))
```

Basicamente la función reduce recibe 3 argumentos:

1. Una función que recibe dos argumentos, el primero es el objeto acumulante que en este caso una instancia de la clase `Registro` y como segundo argumento, el objeto actual de la lista sobre la cual se esta iterando. Esta función debe retornar el objeto acumulante actualizado que va ser pasado la siguientes vez que sea llamada esta función pero ahora con el siguiente elemento dentro del iterable.
2. El segundo argumento representa un iterable que es justamente la estructura sobre la cual se va iterar
3. El tercer argumento es es el valor inicial del objeto acumulante.

Basicamente lo que hace reduce es toma el valor acumulante definido en el tercer argumento `Registro()`, después llama la función `registrar` con el valor acumulante como primer argumento y el primer elemento del iterable como segundo argumento, finalmente el resultado retornado se vuelve el nuevo acumulante y se repite el proceso pero ahora tomando en consideración el segundo valor de iterable, el proceso se repite hasta terminar de recorrer el iterable.

Comment: `reduce` recibe `mezclar`, no?

Comment: Perdón, lo modifique a `registrar`, básicamente registra los datos del cliente en el registro que lleva el acumulante.

Comment: +1 Por la mucho mejor legibilidad usando `reduce`

Comment: gracias me fue de ayuda, además muy interesante :D

Answer (score 1):

En realidad se puede, lo que la verdad no estoy seguro si es un buen método.
Como ya usas comprensión de listas y manejo de diccionarios en tu pregunta creo que no merece mayor explicación:

la lista ya mencionada:

```
clientes = [
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 30000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 22000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 28000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 23000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 18000
    }
]

dic_comp = {x.get('abonado'):0 + sum([z.get('valor_a_pagar') for z in clientes if z.get('abonado') == x.get('abonado')]) for x in clientes }
```

no hay mucha ciencia, una compresión de listas dentro de la comprensión de diccionarios

```
print(dic_comp)
```

Devuelve:

```
{'amazon_prime': 103000, 'netflix': 88000}
```

Viendo las otras respuestas te digo: si se puede, lo que repito porque no lo e visto es si se debe, aunque si funciona no veo porque no.

Comment: muchas gracias, pensaba que la única solución podía ser usar `reduce`

Comment: Ok, aunque es raro que haya una única solución, depende de la aplicación de los diferentes paradigmas de programación y sus métodos.

Comment: OJO, que esta solución es de orden O(n²), si el diccionario tiene pocos datos, no importa tanto, pero a medida que tenga más y más datos, su eficiencia será bastante pobre con respecto de las que recorren la lista una sola vez, que son de orden O(n).